# Conditional Formatting Largest Value Cell Across Columns // Count Cells by Color

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, conditional-formatting

I am looking to use conditional formatting to shade the largest value in each column across 6 different columns.

In the image, you'll see 7 different entries (Entry A-G) and 6 judges scoring each entry. For each judge, I want to shade the highest score. The second image is the result I am looking for.

Also, is there a way to count number of green cells in a new column? For example, for Entry B, there is one first place. For entry C, there are two first places.

[image]

[image]

I used conditional formatting with the formula: `=B2=MAX($B2:$G8)`

But random cells are highlighted when I apply this formula. The second image is the result I'm looking for - for example, Judge 1 is cell B7 for Entry F with a score of 6.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Regarding "a way to count number of green cells in a new column," that's a second question and I would recommend posting it separately. There is a deprecated way that doesn't work for my version of Excel (Microsoft 365 for Enterprise Version 2309).

Essentially, it's using GET.CELL in Defined Name.

However, would you want a formula method or would VBA or Office Script work?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with the conditional formatting formula. To look for the max in a column, change it to this:

`=B2=MAX(B$2:B$9)`

Have this apply to the range `=$B$2:$G$8`
[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

For the Formula use

```
=MAX(B$2:B$8)
```

and for the Applies to

```
=$B$2:$G$8
```