# Count Cells by Color

Tags: excel

I have this table attached where the highest number in each **column **has been conditionally formatted green. I want to count the number of green cells in each **row** (see column H).

Is there a formula or conditional formatting I can use to count cells by color?

[image]

Comment: Formula do not see formatting.  So instead of counting the color.  Count how many times the cell in that row is the max for that column.

Comment: Please share some feedback. So that we know that solution posted resolves the issue or not, as far I understand the formula should resolve your problem and using color as a counting reference is not a good idea. Instead use the formula as suggested !

Answer (score 1):

Formula do not see formatting. So instead of counting the color. Count how many times the cell in that row is the max for that column

With Office 365 put this in H2 and copy down:

```
=SUM(BYCOL($B$2:$G$8,LAMBDA(a,--(INDEX(a,ROW($Z1))=MAX(a)))))
```

[image]

---

Or Just this in H2 to spill the results:

```
=LET(rng,B2:G8,BYROW(rng=BYCOL(rng,LAMBDA(a,MAX(a))),LAMBDA(x,SUM(--x))))
```

[image]

---

For older versions we can use MAXIFS to return an array of the max number by column and compare that using SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:G2=MAXIFS(OFFSET($B$2:$B$8,0,COLUMN($B$2:$G$8)-MIN(COLUMN($B$2:$G$8))),OFFSET($B$2:$B$8,0,COLUMN($B$2:$G$8)-MIN(COLUMN($B$2:$G$8))),">0")))
```

[image]

Comment: Sir very interesting solution, is it possible with `MMULT()` ?

Comment: A solution with MMULT did not come to mind.  There might be, but not sure.

Comment: I re-read what you wrote like 4/5 times, i found the logic which you have stated is deep and makes sense. I am trying with `MMULT()` but seems bit difficult. But Amazing I liked your solution.

Comment: Sir, I figured out but strange it doesnt work when i enter the formula shown in cell `I1` within the `SUM()` function as in the screenshot, it uses it as a helper column, and neither with `MMULT()` also, if you kindly check the **[Screenshot](https://imgur.com/gallery/TKoXfAT)**

Comment: I am unsure why, but I found the same which is why I went way back to using OFFSET.

Comment: Ah alright sir, I am trying to research more on it, Thank you very much for sharing this solution, it fascinated me to think more. Thanks again!! Also OP posted this same question in the morning for conditional formatting and counts. Just saw it now **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77364005/8162520)**

Comment: Sir bit shorter without two `LAMBDA()`s -> `=MMULT(N(B2:G8=BYCOL(B2:G8,LAMBDA(a,MAX(a)))),TOCOL(B1:G1)+1)`